# Detached Expo app gets error on IOS TestFlight

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I have a detached app which is working fine on my local when I am running with xcode, but when I deploy it for TestFlight I get this expo version error at load.

> The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v25.0.0, but this copy of Expo  Client requires at least v29.0.0. The author should update their experience to a newer Expo SDK version

### [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49hVk.jpg)

And this is my EXSDKVersions.plist

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>detachedNativeVersions</key>
        <dict>
            <key>kernel</key>
            <string>29.0.0</string>
            <key>shell</key>
            <string>29.0.0</string>
        </dict>
        <key>sdkVersions</key>
        <array>
            <string>29.0.0</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason but the following helped me

```
1) rm -rf node_modules && npm install
2) go to ios folder
3) rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock build && pod install
```